# android auto - notifications without reply

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-auto

I'd like my android auto notification to not have any reply mechanism to it.  I just want a notification that you can swipe to dismiss, but the only two options i see for android auto are messaging and audio.  The messaging makes the notification have a reply to it like this:

[image]

notice how there is a microphone for user to reply. I dont want that on my notification. I only want to display info but no reply mechanism. I am not interested in reply, only to notify user of something.   i want it to look like this instead but it seems only system has this kinds of notifications. [image]

Comment: Is there now any way to show only notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Auto has defined guidelines for Messaging Apps.
It didn't consider normal notifications as a scenario that needs to be addressed now in Auto environment.
We can hope it may be made more flexible on future along with measures to make sure that distraction is avoided by strict certification process.

So the answer to your question is - Not possible now.